# I can't find the values of the currents

Tags: current, voltage-regulator, analog, design

The picture below is on page 7 of the datasheet of TL497, it is a switching regulator that I use as an inverting regulator (it has an inverting mode) to generate -24V from 12V in input, in the first designing equation on this page I have 2 unknowns "I(pk)" and "Io max" I don't know how can I find their values ?? In the datasheet it is wrote that I(pk) maximum value is 500mA so if I(pk) in the equation means 500mA why they didn't write 500mA simply unless of I(pk) also I(pk) max value is 500mA it can be lower than that and if 500mA means the "Io max" then I(pk) value will be 3A for VI=12V and |Vo|=24V which is impossible because I(pk) max =500mA. I hope I explained well. 
datasheet:http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/405/tl497a-405896.pdf
[image]

Comment: It doesn't say that Ipk is 500 mA.  It says that in order to use the  basic configuration with the internal transistor then your application must have an Ipk less than 500mA.  And the Ipk is the Ipk given in the formula.  If you calculate Ipk greater than 500 mA using the given formula then you must use an external transistor.

Comment: Are you and @oussama working on the same thing? You should get together and work it out.  =-D  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/243642/how-to-choose-the-transistor-and-the-resistors-connected-to-it

Answer (score 1):

IO max is your maximum load current - how much current you need to run your load at the output voltage.  Calculate I(PK) using the equation you have circled and as @scorpdaddy says, if its less than 500 ma you are ok without the external transistor.  Otherwise add the transistor.

Choose Rcl to give you the current sense you need, and choose a transistor with a collector current in excess of your calculated I(pk).  Choose appropriate base resistor divider values low enough for sufficient base current.

Comment: @scorpdaddy Thank you now I understand, but if the current that I need is more than 500mA, 700mA for example haw can I choose the transistor and the resistances between pin 10 and pin 13 ?

Comment: Birchead Thank you now I understand, but if the current that I need is more than 500mA, 700mA for example haw can I choose the transistor and the resistances between pin 10 and pin 13 ?