# How to choose the transistor and the resistors connected to it

Tags: transistors, voltage-regulator, circuit-analysis, analog

I am using the regulator TL497 in the case of I(pk)>500mA so I need an external transistor for that but in the datasheet they don't mention how to choose the transistor and its resistors does anyone has an idea about that ?
Datasheet:http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/405/tl497a-405896.pdf
[image]

Comment: The component selection will depend on just *what* peak current you need to deal with.

Comment: For the resistors you have the formulas in datasheet file.

Comment: @PeterSmith The pick current is almost 1A so I think I need to choose a transistor with Ic>1A but what about the resistors ?

Comment: @Michael: In which page ? I am not talking about the resistors of the output I am talking about the resistors connected to the transistor.

Comment: Are you and @berem working on the same thing? You should get together and work it out.  =-D  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/243560/i-cant-find-the-values-of-the-currents

Comment: This question needs work: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask "Does anyone have any idea"... is not specific as required by the forum guidelines. If you want to, greatly improve your question edit it and ask to reopen it. Professional questions will get professional answers. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First, redraw the schematic so we can see what is going on:

[image: TL497 with outboard switch]

This makes it clear that the internal switch is not in circuit and is being used to control the external switch (the PNP in the datasheet).

The design procedure:

1. Choose your current limit resistor - this is in the datasheet.

The next step is a bit iterative:

2. Choose a transistor that can handle the *average* current as well as the peak current. Try and find a device that has a large value of \$h_{fe}\$ in saturation.
3. The transistor will dissipate at least \$V_{CE(sat)}\cdot I_{load} \cdot D\$ where D is the duty cycle of the regulator, so choose a package that can handle that power (you could heatsink it for a smaller package size).
4. Choose the top resistor: This must be sized so that it provides enough base current, \$I_B\$ at \$V_{CE(sat)}\$; this can be found in the datasheet. For instance, if \$I_{load}\$ is 1A and \$H_{fe}\$ is 10 in saturation, this resistor must be \$\lt \frac {0.7} {100mA}\$ - it is less than that as this resistor also supplies the collector of the internal switch - I would normally give that switch perhaps a few mA. That yields about \$6.4\Omega\$. Make sure you choose a device that can handle the power (I will leave that calculation to you).
5. Choose the internal switch bias resistor. This must be sized such that the internal switch goes fully to saturation and also must handle extra current not injected into the base across temperature (and across batches for that matter). This is given by Vin - 0.5 (current limit sense value) - 0.7V (the emitter base drop on the PNP) / assumed collector current - I used 10mA yielding \$ \frac {V_{in} - 1.2} {I_{c}}\$. As this is Vin dependent, I will leave that calculation to you.
6. The added external diode is now the freewheeling device, so I would choose a power schottky to keep the losses low; the current in this device is dependent on duty cycle and without knowing Vin I cannot do the numbers but a 3A rated device would easily suffice.

The thermal calculations are based on average current. I would normally choose a transistor that could take the peak current continuously; peak pulse current ratings vs. continuous current can be a bit misleading from datasheets due to the test method.

Comment: Thank you very much, did you mean by Iload I(pk) or Io max ?